# Search Wordnik API by topic?

Tags: wordnik

When I use the relatedWords API endpoint, I see the word "flower" has_topic "Home & Garden". But I can't quite figure out how to use the API query just this topic. How can I find out what else is listed under the topic "Home & Garden"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking about the Wordnik API!

We have some of this data right now but don't yet have an API endpoint to get words by topic. If you'd like to be notified when that endpoint is in beta, please join our beta-announcements list: https://us2.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=1c9b004e359a58df355705423&id=e142268969.

Because we're a tiny nonprofit with limited engineering resources, I don't have a release date yet, but this is high on our roadmap.